# Django- how to save form input to an object model in the database?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django project which is being used to manage a number of projects, and all of the information relating to a project.

On one of the webpages, titled 'Concept', there is a form, which takes an input value of cost excluding vat in one text box, displays the cost including vat in another text box, and has a `datepicker` field to allow the user to select the date that a deposit has been paid, if it has at all.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the form to save the value entered by the user for the date at the moment- if the user fills out the three fields in the form (cost exc vat- entered by user, cost inc vat- automatically generated based on const exc vat, & date), and then refreshes the page, the two cost fields retain their values, but the 'date' field reverts to being blank.

When I inspect the page element for the 'date' field, I can see that it is in the following HTML structure:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <form method="POST" .... data-view-url=".../concept_save_ajax/">
                <div class="col-12-box">
                    <div>
                        <table class="right fixed m-t-md">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    ...
                                    <td class="p-r-md">Deposit exc VAT</td>
                                    <td class="p-r-md">
                                        <input class="currency" id="id_amount_exc_vat" name="amount_exc_vat" type="number" value="280">
                                    <td class="p-r-md>
                                        <input class="datepicker hasDatepicker" data-original-value id="id_date_received" name="date_received" type="text"> == $0
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Edit**

Although that is the structure of the HTML for the page when I 'inspect it in the browser, the actual code from my HTML file in my project is:

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-vat-status="{{project.vat_status}}" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:concept_save_ajax_2' project.id %}" class="autosave_form formset full-width" action="{% url 'projects:upload_budget_pdfs' project.id %}">
        ...
    </form>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-vat-status="{{project.vat_status}}" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:concept_save_ajax' project.id %}" class="autosave_form full-width">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="col-12 box">
            <div>
                <table class="right fixed m-t-md">
                    <tr>
                        {% for hidden in deposit_form.hidden_fields %}
                            {{hidden}}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for field in deposit_form.visible_fields %}
                            <td class="p-r-md">{{field.label}}</td><td class="p-r-md">{{field}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <td><a class="email_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=7">Raise invoice</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 box">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 box">
            ...
        </div>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

**End Edit**

Given that the form method is specified as `POST`, I am expecting the information entered into the form to be saved using the `concept_save_ajax` view as indicated inside the opening `<form>` tag.

This view is defined in `views.py` with:

```
def concept_save_ajax(request, project_id):
""" Save concept forms """
if not request.is_ajax():
    raise Http404('Ajax only')

if request.method == 'POST':
    project = Project.objects.prefetch_related('budget_versions', 'budget_overview').get(pk=project_id)

    form_instances = [
        # [DepositForm, project.deposit],
        [DepositInfoForm, project.deposit],
        [BudgetNotesForm, project.budget_overview],
        [EndDetailsForm, project.end],
    ]

    # Save the forms 
    for form_instance in form_instances:
        form = form_instance[0](request.POST, instance=form_instance[0]) #1]) should be '0' for first element?
        if form.is_valid() and form.has_changed():
            print form_instance[0], "is valid.", form_instance[0]
            updated_details = form.save()
        elif form.has_changed():
            print form_instance[0], "is not valid", form.errors
            return JsonResponse({'error': form.errors})



    # url = '/projects/{0}/?tab={1}'.format(project_id, tabs[3])
    return JsonResponse({'success': 'Saved'})
else:
    raise Http404('Request is not a post')
```

I can see that this view is calling `form.save()` if and when the criteria `form.is_valid()` and `form.has_changed()` is met, but for some reason this doesn't appear to actually save when I enter a new value for the 'date' field.

I have tried to test this in the console- but the field that should be holding the 'date' value appears to be empty... In the console, I ran:

```
 from projects import models

 from projects.models import Project

 allPrjcts = Project.objects.all()

 br = allPrjcts.filter(project_name="1 Brocks Road")

 from costing import models

 from costing.models import Deposit

 allDpsts = Deposit.objects.all()

 brocksRoad = br[0]          # I know that this is the only project returned by the filter

brDpst = allDpsts.get(project_id = 6311L)      # I know that this is the ID for the 'brocksRoad' project
```

But then, when I run `brDpst.date_received` in the console, nothing is shown, indicating that the value I entered into the 'date' field on the webpage doesn't appear to have been saved...

Any ideas why this is? How can I get the value of the 'date' field to save automatically, so that it is displayed when I reload the page, the same as the 'cost' fields on that form?

If I run `brDpst.amount_exc_vat` in the console, it displays the value:

> Decimal('280.00')

which is the amount I input into the text box, so clearly the form is saving... just for some reason the value of the 'date' field is not being retained...

**Edit**

This is how the `DepositInfoForm` is currently defined:

```
class DepositInfoForm(ValidatedForm):
    ...
    date_received = MoonDateField(required=False, label="Date deposit received", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs=({'class':'datepicker'})))
```

I tried changing it to:

```
class DepositInfoForm(ValidatedForm):
    ...
    date_received = MoonDateField(required=False, label="Date deposit received", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs=({'class':'datepicker', 'type':'date'})))
```

as suggested by @neverwalkaloner, but if I do this, there are now two calendars displayed in the drop down when I select the `date_received` field on the form... I want to use the calendar that's already there to choose the date, not the one that was added by the `'type':'date'` parameter that I passed to the `date_received` variable...

**Edit**

I've added some debug to my `DepositInfoForm(...)` class, and it seems that its `save()` method is being called when changes are made to the form field that's taking the numerical value, but `save()` is not being called when changes are made to the form field that's holding the date... I don't understand why this is...?

The `DepositInfoForm(...)` class is defined with:

```
class DepositInfoForm(ValidatedForm):
    amount_exc_vat = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'currency',}),label="Deposit exc VAT")
    amount_inc_vat = forms.IntegerField(required=False, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'currency', 'readonly':'readonly',}),label="Inc VAT")
    date_received = MoonDateField(required=False, label="Date deposit received", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs=({'class':'datepicker'})))

    class Meta:
        model = Deposit
        fields = ('amount_exc_vat', 'amount_inc_vat', 'date_received')#,'received')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "__init__ method being called in DepositInfoForm"
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project

        try: amount_exc_vat = int(round(instance.amount_exc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_exc_vat = None
        try: amount_inc_vat = int(round(project.deposit.amount_inc_vat))
        except TypeError: amount_inc_vat = None

        try: date_received = instance.date_received
        except TypeError: date_received = None

        initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
        initial={
                    'received': project.deposit_received,
                    'amount_exc_vat': amount_exc_vat,
                    'amount_inc_vat': amount_inc_vat,
                    'date_received': date_received,
                }
        kwargs['initial'] = initial

        super(DepositInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_received'].widget.attrs.update({'data-original-value': self.initial['date_received'] or ''})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        print "Save method being called in DepositInfoForm"
        deposit = self.instance
        data = self.cleaned_data

        print "save method being called in DepositInfoForm (projects/forms.py line 1142)"
        if 'date_received' in self.changed_data:
            if not data['date_received'] == '':
                deposit.project.deposit_received = True;
                self.deposit_r = True
                deposit.project.upgrade_detailed_status(Project.ds75)
        else:
            deposit.project.deposit_received = False;       
        deposit.project.save()

        if ('amount_exc_vat' in self.changed_data or 'date_received' in self.changed_data in self.changed_data) and data['amount_exc_vat'] and data['date_received']:
            send_message(message_template=2, project=self.instance.project)
            self.deposit_r = True       

        if hasattr(self, 'deposit_r'):
            # Make the payment
            deposit_payment = Payment(project=deposit.project, is_booking_deposit=True, amount_exc_vat=data['amount_exc_vat'], date_paid=data['date_received'])

        return super(DepositInfoForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

**Edit**

when I try to change the date in the form on the webpage at the moment, although the new date is displayed initially, if I refresh the page, its value changes back to what it was before I changed it. When I change the value of the 'date' field in the form, the console is displaying the following output:

```
 Exception in thread Thread-42:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File ".../models.py", line 138, in run
msg.send(self.fail_silently)
  File ".../message.py", line 292, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File ".../smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
  File ".../smtp.py", line 67, in open
self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File ".../smtplib.py", line 615, in login
raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')
```

but I haven't actually changed any of the files it's complaining about in the `Traceback`... What would be causing this exception?

Comment: You need to show the code for your forms, and the format of the data you are submitting.

Comment: I've edited my OP to show the definition of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because date_received has type=text instead of type=date.
Try to change your forms:

```
class DepositInfoForm(forms.Form):
    date_received = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
                            {
                                'class':'datepicker hasDatepicker',
                                'type':'date'  
                            })
```

Comment: Because the HTML is written in Django, and not normal HTML, I don't have access to the individual elements in the form... so I'm not sure how I would change the `type` for this element on the form? I've updated my OP to show the Django code in the HTML file.

Comment: @someone2088 Find code of class DepositInfoForm and try to change date_received field as in my answer.

Comment: The `date_received` field is defined in the form with the line: `date_received = mDateField(required=False, label="Date deposit received", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs=({'class':'datepicker'})))`, i.e. it doesn't currently have a `type` attribute...

Comment: @someone2088 try to add it.

Comment: I tried adding it, but when I view the page, I then have two different calendars displayed in the drop down when I select that input field... I would expect that I want to be using the one that was originally there, and not the one I've added by adding the `'type':'date'`...

Comment: @someone2088 please show the code. How it was and how became after corrections.

Comment: I have edited my post to show the changes I've made as you suggested- and highlighted the problems that doing this gives me.